# Find the classification rate of testing data

Tags: matlab, for-loop, knn

I need to use [KNN search](http://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/classification-using-nearest-neighbors.html#btap7k2) to classify the testing data and find the classification rate.

Below is the matlab code:
for example:

```
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
    load fisheriris
    x = meas(:,3:4); % x =all training data

    y = [5 1.45;6 2;2.75 .75]; % y =3 testing data 

    [n,d] = knnsearch(x,y,'k',10);   % find the 10 nearest neighbors to three testing data

    for b=1:3
    tabulate(species(n(b,:)))
    end
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
```

The result was display in Command window:

```
tabulate(species(n(1,:)))
       Value    Count   Percent
   virginica        2     20.00%
  versicolor        8     80.00%

tabulate(species(n(2,:)))
      Value    Count   Percent
  virginica       10    100.00%

tabulate(species(n(3,:)))
       Value    Count   Percent
  versicolor        7     70.00%
      setosa        3     30.00%
```

If the testing points are 'Versicolor',the result of first and third testing point are classify correctly and second testing point is wrong one.So the classification rate is 2/3 x100%=66.7%.

Is there any idea to modify the matlab code to find the classification rate automatically and save the result into the Workspace?

Answer (score 1):

In general you can find the number of correct predictions by using

```
sum(predicted_class == true_class)        % For numerical data
sum(strcmp(predicted_class, true_class))  % For cellstrings
```

Or as a percentage

```
100 * sum(predicted_class == true_class) / length(predicted_class)
```

In the case of `fisheriris` the true class would be `species`. For your constructed data it would be

```
true_classes = [cellstr('versicolor'); cellstr('versicolor'); cellstr('versicolor')]
```

In the case of nearest neighbours, the true classes would be the class of the nearest neighbour(s). For a single neighbour:

```
 predicted_class = species(n)
```

Where `n` is the index of the nearest neighbour as found by `[n, d] = knnsearch(x, y)`.

```
sum(strcmp(predicted_class, true_class))
% result: 1
```

Which is indeed correct when you use only one neighbor.

Comment: how to find the classification rate if using k=5 instead of 1?

Comment: if i wanna test another species such as 'virginica',i need to take time to change the true_class from 'versicolor' to 'virginica',is there any ways to change it automatically??

Comment: For `k=5`: that is certainly possible, but maybe worth a new question. For chaking `true_class`: that depends on where the `y = [5 1.45;6 2;2.75 .75];` is comming from; if it's from a data set, the `true_class` is probably also recorded. If you are just making up that data though, you have to make up the `true_class` too.